# Connecting Snowflake to Postgres through Foreign Data Wrapper

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

How can I establish a direct connection between a Snowflake and a Postgres server running on an Ubuntu Linux VM using Postgres Foreign Data Wrapper without relying on an ETL tool?

It appears that there are no readily available Snowflake Foreign Data Wrappers for this purpose. My current approach involves using Postgres Foreign Data Wrappers with ODBC or JDBC to connect to the respective Snowflake driver. Do you have any recommendations for an alternative strategy or insights on how to execute this plan, including the installation and usage guidance?